# CONVERT to datetime fails on Dynamic SQL - "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql, datetime

I've spent a few hours with this and still can't get it to work. I'm trying to get the path to the most recent file that matches a pattern for a dynamic SQL query where I'm loading a CSV file into a temp table for a stored procedure. The original SQL that I built the dynamic query on works perfectly fine (yes, I know CONCAT isn't in this one, but it shouldn't make a difference):

```
DECLARE @FILE varchar(MAX)
SET @FILE = '%InventoryFeedResults%.csv';

DECLARE @FILES TABLE (ID int IDENTITY, [FileInfo] varchar(MAX))
            INSERT INTO @FILES EXECUTE xp_cmdshell 'dir "C:\Inventory Feeds"'
            SELECT [FileName]
            FROM (SELECT ID
                        ,CAST(LEFT([FileInfo],18) AS datetime) AS 'Created'
                        ,RIGHT([FileInfo],CHARINDEX(CHAR(32), REVERSE([FileInfo]),1)-1) AS 'FileName'
                        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CONVERT(datetime,LEFT([FileInfo],18)) DESC) AS 'RowNum'
                    FROM @FILES
                    WHERE [FileInfo] LIKE @FILE) AS FileInfo
            WHERE FileInfo.RowNum = 1
```

But when I try to run it here I get the "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string" error:

```
DECLARE @DIR varchar(MAX)
SET @DIR = 'C:\Inventory Feeds\';
DECLARE @FILE varchar(MAX)
SET @FILE = '%InventoryFeedResults%.csv';

DECLARE @FINDFEED nvarchar(MAX), @PARAM nvarchar(MAX), @PATH nvarchar(MAX)
    SELECT @FINDFEED = 'DECLARE @FILES TABLE (ID int IDENTITY, [FileInfo] varchar(MAX))
                INSERT INTO @FILES EXECUTE xp_cmdshell ''dir "'+ @DIR + '" /b''
                SELECT @ADD = CONCAT(''' + @DIR + ''',[FileName]) 
                            FROM (SELECT ID
                            ,CAST(LEFT([FileInfo],18) AS datetime) AS ''Created''
                            ,RIGHT([FileInfo],CHARINDEX(CHAR(32), REVERSE([FileInfo]),1)-1) AS ''FileName''
                            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CONVERT(datetime,LEFT([FileInfo],18)) DESC) AS ''RowNum''
                        FROM @FILES
                        WHERE [FileInfo] LIKE ''' + @FILE + ''') AS FileInfo
                        WHERE FileInfo.RowNum = 1'
    SELECT @PARAM = '@ADD nvarchar(500) OUTPUT'
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @FINDFEED, @PARAM, @ADD = @PATH OUTPUT

    SELECT @PATH
```

The dates are nvarchars in this format, EX:  '2019-02-15 10:29:00.000'

The filenames are formatted with a report name and a 3 digit number, EX: InventoryFeedResults924.csv

The full output for `FileInfo` is:

```
02/15/2019  10:29 AM           405,609 InventoryFeedResults924.csv
```

This needs to work on SQL Server 12.

I've tried switching between CAST and CONVERT and a few different style numbers in CONVERT, but I'm honestly not sure why it would work one place and not the other. I just need to know what magical incantation that will let me convert this string to a datetime in a dynamic query so I can pull the most recent file if it's possible. Or maybe I could add an option to xp_cmdshell to format the timestamp to make it work? I'm at a loss, help me please, Internet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second example is using the `/b` switch which only returns file names, but not any date information.  Removing the `/b` should fix the problem.